# UI not updated when grouping gridview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, telerik, grouping

Xaml for dynamic grid

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="RadgridHoover"
                                 CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                                 CanUserInsertRows="True"
                                 ShowColumnHeaders="True"
                                 ShowGroupPanel="{Binding IsShowGroupPanel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 AlternateRowBackground="Transparent"
                                 AlternationCount="2"
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                                 IsReadOnly="True"  
                                 IsFilteringAllowed="True"
                                 EditTriggers="CurrentCellClick"
                                 SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                 EnableColumnVirtualization="False"
                                 EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                                 RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                                 behaviors:GridColumnsBindingBehavior.Columns="{Binding Columns, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding MembersTable, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                                 DataLoadMode="Asynchronous"
                                 >
        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

When grouping data on grid, expand a header group and select a record to edit this selected record. 
After that, I updated data row on grid for selected record in viewmodel:

```
public void UpdateRow(int index, object data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            var row = MembersTable.Rows[index];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.GetType().GetProperties().Count(); i++)
            {
                PropertyInfo pinfo = data.GetType().GetProperties()[i];
                if (!ListPropertiesName.Contains(pinfo.Name))
                {
                    row[pinfo.Name] = pinfo.GetValue(data, null);
                }
            }
            MembersTable.Rows[index] = row;
        }
    }
```

This selected row is not updated, just when i scroll the grid, this selected row is updated.
If not grouping row, everything is okay.

Please help me this case.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For more than the past 2 years `DataLoadMode="Asynchronous"` for RadGridView is not recommended by telerik guys. Looks like they themself have broken the feature in new releases.

If you are OK for changing `DataLoadMode` to something other than `Asynchronous` the issue might get resolved.

Checkout http://www.telerik.com/forums/dataloadmode-asynchronous-is-not-recommended